# Python; urllib error: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Note: This is Python 3, there is no urllib2.  Also, I've tried using json.loads(), and I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I get this error if I use json.loads() and remove the .read() from response:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

>

```
import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/r/all/top/.json').read()
jsonResponse = json.load(response)

for child in jsonResponse['data']['children']:
    print (child['data']['title'])
```

Does not work... I have no idea why.

Comment: in what way doesn't it work?  try `urllib2.urlopen` instead

Comment: I saved a lot of headaches by using the `http.client`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try this:

```
jsonResponse = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: For me, it was `json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: it this bug in only 3.5 version ?

Comment: I have got error

Answer (score 46):

Use `json.loads` not `json.load`.

(`load` loads from a file-like object, `loads` from a string. So you could just as well omit the `.read()` call instead.)

Comment: Does not work.  If you include the .read, this error is prompted: TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

If you remove the .read(), you get this error: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with python 3 yet, but it seems like `urllib.request.urlopen().read()` returns a `byte` object rather than string.

You might try to feed it into a `StringIO` object, or even do a `str(response)`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `{AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'}` in python3.
This worked for me later without using json:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://someurl/'
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.prettify('latin-1'))
```