# How to convert Instagram API response to Python 3 dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, instagram

I'm using Python 3 to get the response from Instagram API using the code below

```
 instagramJSON = xRequest(nextUrl)
 print (instagramJSON)
 instagramDict = json.load(instagramJSON)
```

the `xRequest` method gets the response from the Instagram API URL, when I print the object it looks like a legit JSON object but when I do the `json.load` method on it I get the following error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'`

The same code works on Python 2 , I tried to search for it Python docs for Python3 but no luck. Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can also use python-requests which has built-in support for JSON, just call `.json()` on the response object.

Comment: thanks for the tip Andre, I tried and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If the `instagramJSON` is a `str` then you should use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`. If `instagramJSON` is a string then it would have raised the same exception in Python 2 so there may be more going on.

[Python JSON documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

If it is a response generated by `urllib.request` then the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541767/python-urllib-error-attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-read) may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But even if I run it with `json.loads` I get `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`