# How to parse JSON from URL and download CSV files?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I'm given a URL which contains some JSON text. In the text there are URL's for csv files. I'm trying to parse the JSON from the URL and download the CSV files. I am able to print out the JSON from the URL but do not know how to grab the CSV files from within.

```
import urllib, json
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://staging.test.com/api/reports/68.json?auth_token=test") as url:
    s = url.read()
print(s)
```

The above will print the JSON from the URL ( see below printout), there are URL's for csv files that I then need to download using python.

```
{"id":68,"name":"Carrier Rates","state":"complete","user_id":166,"data_set_id":7,"bounding_date":{"id":101,"start_date":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00","end_date":"2999-12-31T00:00:00.000-05:00","bounding_field_id":322,"related_id":68,"related_type":"Reports::Report"},"results":[{"id":68,"created_at":"2019-07-26T15:29:40.872-04:00","version_name":"07/26/2019 03:29PM","content":"https://test-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.1dec2e6d-0c36-44b7-ab26-fd43fe710daf.csv"},{"id":67,"created_at":"2019-07-26T15:29:07.112-04:00","version_name":"07/26/2019 03:29PM","content":"https://test-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.3b02195e-c0a2-4abe-88f7-27d20ac76e07.csv"},{"id":35,"created_at":"2019-06-26T11:01:26.900-04:00","version_name":"06/26/2019 11:01AM","content":"https://test-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.a488c58d-5e04-4c28-a429-7167e9e8edaa.csv"},{"id":34,"created_at":"2019-06-26T10:57:51.396-04:00","version_name":"06/26/2019 10:57AM","content":"https://cloudtestlogistics-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.bf73db19-5604-4a1d-bc31-da6cf25742cc.csv"}]}
```

Comment: Please let us know if you have tried anything to parse the JSON text., How far did you get?

Comment: Looks like the post from Muhammad Danial Khan below will work however I am getting the error AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read' , not sure if im missing library or something

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it a guide/tutorial resource. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: my initial post is what ive already tried, I was able to pull the json from the URL however I needed some guidance on downloading the links to the csv's in the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can help you.

```
    import json
    import urllib.request

    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://staging.test.com/api/reports/68.json?auth_token=test") as url:
    s = url.read()
    loadJson = json.load(s)
    results = loadJson["results"]
    csvLinks = []
    for object in results:
        csvlinks.append(object["content"])
```

Now you have a list of links to CSV files. Download them using urllib.

Comment: this looks like it can work however I get this error. Not sure if missing library or something else: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541767/python-urllib-error-attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-read/6541850

Comment: Thanks that worked, adding this jsonResponse = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

#This is your "s"  -- data = s
data = '{"name": "John Smith", "hometown": {"name": "New York", "id": 123}}'

# Parse JSON into an object with attributes corresponding to dict keys.
x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
print x.name, x.hometown.name, x.hometown.id
```

This answer from: [How to convert JSON data into a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object) loads Json into an object.  Now access it via the key it was passed with in json.

```
print x.content
```

Of course you'll have to wiggle the code around to get it to work exactly how you want.  I'm not really a python expert and have nothing to test with.  But the idea is to just load it into a Tuple object and access it via the key.

Comment: Is that Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib, json
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://staging.test.com/api/reports/68.json?auth_token=test") as url:
    s = url.read()

# assuming here you got that json content
s='{"id":68,"name":"Carrier Rates","state":"complete","user_id":166,"data_set_id":7,"bounding_date":{"id":101,"start_date":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00","end_date":"2999-12-31T00:00:00.000-05:00","bounding_field_id":322,"related_id":68,"related_type":"Reports::Report"},"results":[{"id":68,"created_at":"2019-07-26T15:29:40.872-04:00","version_name":"07/26/2019 03:29PM","content":"https://test-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.1dec2e6d-0c36-44b7-ab26-fd43fe710daf.csv"},{"id":67,"created_at":"2019-07-26T15:29:07.112-04:00","version_name":"07/26/2019 03:29PM","content":"https://test-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.3b02195e-c0a2-4abe-88f7-27d20ac76e07.csv"},{"id":35,"created_at":"2019-06-26T11:01:26.900-04:00","version_name":"06/26/2019 11:01AM","content":"https://test-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.a488c58d-5e04-4c28-a429-7167e9e8edaa.csv"},{"id":34,"created_at":"2019-06-26T10:57:51.396-04:00","version_name":"06/26/2019 10:57AM","content":"https://cloudtestlogistics-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/manufacturer/carrier-test.bf73db19-5604-4a1d-bc31-da6cf25742cc.csv"}]}'

d=json.loads(s)

for f in d['results']:
    # manage download here
    csv_url= f['content']
```