# How to fetch historical ESG data from Yahoo?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to scrape historical ESG data from Sustainalytics on Yahoo Finance using Python. Specifically, let's say I want the last 10 years of ESG scores of a given list of constituents.

The following code lines provides up-to-date ESG scores. But I would like to scrape past-ESG performance.  I am essentially looking for yearly (monthly, if possible) ESG from Jan 2010 till Dec 2020. I would like to automate the scraping and save the data in a txt or csv file.

```
# import yfinance, pandas and os
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import os
```

Code for a single ticker:

```
msft = "MSFT"
msft_y = yf.Ticker(msft)
esg_data = pd.DataFrame.transpose(msft_y.sustainability)
esg_data['company_ticker'] = str(msft_y ticker)
```

It returns a dataframe of 27 rows covering ESG-relevant information for Microsoft.

Code for the S&P 500:

```
# Import list of tickers from file
os.chdir("C:\...")
sp_500 = pd.read_csv('SP_500_tickers.csv')
# Retrieve Yahoo! Finance Sustainability Scores for each ticker
for i in sp_500['ticker_code']:
    # print(i)
    i_y = yf.Ticker(i)
    try:
        if i_y.sustainability is not None:
            temp = pd.DataFrame.transpose(i_y.sustainability)
            temp['company_ticker'] = str(i_y.ticker)
            # print(temp)
            esg_data = esg_data.append(temp)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

It returns a dataframe of ESG data for the S&P500 constituents, which we can use for analysis. The idea behind is to create portfolios of “good” and “bad” ESG companies and compare performance to see how share prices have performed during different historical time periods.

So far, these codes cannot fetch ESG data for past dates.

Comment: Does yfinance come with documentation regarding historic periods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to use requests.get as the connection was forbidden. Error 403. So I tried using urllib.request.urlopen from the StackOverflow board below.
Visit [Python; urllib error: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541767/python-urllib-error-attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-read)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import urllib.request
import json
dataframes = []
url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/esgChart?symbol=A"

connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = connection.read()
data_2 = json.loads(data)
Formatdata = data_2["esgChart"]["result"][0]["symbolSeries"]
Formatdata_2 = pd.DataFrame(Formatdata)
Formatdata_2["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(Formatdata_2["timestamp"], unit="s")
```

Preview prints the data as shown by putty

```
print(Formatdata_2.head())
```

The rest of the code was adapted from putty

Answer (score 1):

There's a Yahoo Finance endpoint you can use that should give you monthly ESG scores, governance score, environment score, and social score.  Don't think it goes back that far though:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Read in your symbols
sp_500 = pd.read_csv("SP_500_tickers.csv")

# Endpoint
url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/esgChart"

# List of dataframes
dataframes = []

for symbol in sp_500["ticker_code"]:
    response = requests.get(url, params={"symbol": symbol})
    if response.ok:
        df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()["esgChart"]["result"][0]["symbolSeries"]
        df["symbol"] = symbol
        dataframes.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dataframes)
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="s")
```

Preview:

```
>>> df.head()
   timestamp  esgScore  governanceScore  environmentScore  socialScore symbol
0 2014-09-01      61.0             62.0              74.0         45.0   AAPL
1 2014-10-01      60.0             62.0              74.0         45.0   AAPL
2 2014-11-01      61.0             62.0              74.0         45.0   AAPL
3 2014-12-01      61.0             62.0              74.0         45.0   AAPL
4 2015-01-01      61.0             62.0              74.0         45.0   AAPL
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you

Comment: Could you please send me the SP_500_tickers.csv file?

Answer (score 0):

1 Go to Yahoo Finance.
2 Enter a quote into the search field.
3 Select a quote in the search results to view it.
4 Click Historical Data.
5 Select a Time Period, data to Show, and Frequency.
6 Click Apply.
7 To use the data offline, [click Download](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2311.html).